# I am trying to create a table in SQL and keep getting an error

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata SQL assistant to create a table.  The code I am using is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
( 
     CalendarKey INT NOT NULL,
     FullDate DATE NOT NULL,
     DayOfWeek VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     DayOfMonth INT NOT NULL,
     Month VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     Qtr VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     Year VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL

     PRIMARY KEY (CalendarKey)
);
```

I get this error when I try to execute the command:

> [Teradata Database] [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a 'CHECK' keyword between ',' and the 'Month' keyword.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: SQL Server (MSSQL) <> MySQL.. Also the tagging also seams totally wrong..  As the error suggests [TeraData](https://www.teradata.com/) as RDMS

Comment: The tags have been fixed

Comment: I do not know the TeraData `CREATE TABLE ..` structure with the datatypes and or indexes.. But there is a comma missing.. after `Year VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL`

Comment: @DaleK it might be.  Do I just need to use a different name for that record?

Comment: @DaleK it was reserved.  I fixed the name and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error implies `month` (and `year`, too) is a reserved keyword in Teradata, which can't be used as column name.

You might double quote it (but then you have to double quote it in every query, too) or you change the name. There's another issue, a missing comma before the `primary key` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
( 
     CalendarKey INT NOT NULL,
     FullDate DATE NOT NULL,
     DayOfWeek VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     DayOfMonth INT NOT NULL,
     "Month" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     Qtr VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     "Year" VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (CalendarKey)
);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I work with Teradata for 20+ years, believe me, the syntax is valid. A logical Primary **Key** is different from a physical Primary **Index**

Comment: *"I work with Teradata for 20+ years, believe me, the syntax is valid."* ok fair enough, it also does not help if the `CREATE TABLE ...` is "explained" on two different locations in the manual...   The more extended [location](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/eWpPpcMoLGQcZEoyt5AjEg/IEGchL9GChJgIJTiksS7tQ) indeed shows this structure aswell..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, the syntax your are calling out is for creating the **primary index**, which is not the same thing as a **primary key**. Primary key, constraints, etc, are inside of the parens.  Primary Index is outside.

Comment: Offtopic: here we go again for the second time today.... anyhow i notice the differences between primary **key** and primary **index** already, like i said before never worked with TeraData, only said it does not help that `CREATE TABLE ..` is on two manual locations it is confusing to say the least.. Anyhow by the way the last sparring session is easy solvable with  ... `.. BETWEEN ... AND ... REPEAT('z', 255)`  i lost the question link by deleting the question wanted to hide it temporary..

Comment: Did you remove that last comment  with the link yourself or the stackoverflow police? As i noticed just before i went to sleep that you posted a comment.. ... Still wierd i can't find that question which i deleted in mine 
Deleted Recent Answers list so if you still can easy find that link and would be kind enough to comment it again that would be great ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (
  CalendarKey INT NOT NULL,
  FullDate DATE NOT NULL,
  DayOfWeek VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  DayOfMonth INT NOT NULL,
  Month VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Qtr VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  Year VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
)
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `calendar` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CalendarKey`);
```

Comment: By making two distinct queries ?
I tried and I have no errors with the code I past you

Comment: Yeah every time I run it, it says there is that same error.

Comment: Looking at the backticks it seems like you run it on mysql.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, to have a table with PK as part of Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
( 
     CalendarKey INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     FullDate DATE NOT NULL,
     [DayOfWeek] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     [DayOfMonth] INT NOT NULL,
     [Month] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     Qtr VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     [Year] VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
);
```

Or this to have Primary Key PK with an Identity [auto counter]

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
( 
     CalendarKey INT PRIMARY KEY Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
     FullDate DATE NOT NULL,
     [DayOfWeek] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     [DayOfMonth] INT NOT NULL,
     [Month] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     Qtr VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     [Year] VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
);
```

- Note, it's recommended to use prackets [] if the col name is a reserved key-word , like [year]

Comment: Thats SQL Server SQL dialect code  SQL tag does not mean SQL Server (MSSQL) on this website..

Comment: I just used the suggested tags. My bad.

Comment: Keywords in square brackets is SQL Server syntax, Standard SQL requires double quotes instead (also supported by SQL Server)